# How to verify Ibatis XML is well formed at build time?

Tags: java, ant, build, ibatis

We are using IBatis 2 in our project. If we have a namespace error or non existant Id for a sql or resultmap in the Ibatis XML, an exception is thrown at runtime when we load the corresponding DAO which calls this SQL map. I am looking for a way to verify the IBATIS xml is well formed at compile time, so that these kind of runtime issues can be avoided.

The 2 ways I can think of are - 1) Extend Ant Task to verify the IBATIS XML. 2) Have a Junit which instantiate each Dao and fails if the we get exception while instantiating the DAO.

Is there any other way to check at compile time the validaity of the IBATIS XML?

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach using JUnit and actually creating an instance of an SqlMapClient is better than using XML validation, since this would not verify class names.